# Adding dollar signs, commas and curly brackets to input list in python 3.5

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I want to add $, commas and curly brackets to my code when it is printed in python 3.5

```
list1 = input('enter four numbers')
```

Once I get the values I print

```
print ('numbers are: ${:,.2f}',format(list1))
```

Once it prints I get

```
numbers are: ${:,.2f} 6 7 8 9
```

The answer should be something like

{$12.95, $1,234.56, $100.00, $20.50}

Comment: `format()` is a method of string objects. Use `'....'.format(...)`, with a *dot*, not a comma.

Comment: @MartijnPieters certainly the reason he's not getting an error here is because he used a comma, not a dot. However if he'd used a dot he'd just get a `TypeError` since he has more objects than places to put them. This isn't as simple as a typo.

Comment: @AdamSmith: fair enough; reopened.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use something like:

```
"Numbers are " + ' '.join("${:,.2f}".format(n) for n in list1)
```

There are basically three operands here:

```
"Numbers are " +
# Just the simple string tacked on the front

' '.join( ... )
# Joins its contents with a space separator

"${:,.2f}".format(n) for n in list1
# Creates a list of the strings with the requested formatting.
```

Unroll that backwards to build a list of the properly formatted strings, join them with a space separator, and tack them on to the end of your static string.

Comment: Once i add this i get an error that  states "Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'" does this mean i need to take of the .2f? thank you for your help so far btw

Comment: @WestLawrence it means when you get the input from the user, they're not numbers yet. You might want to cast them to float as you get them from the user. `list1 = map(float, input("...").split())` or something